# Use VPN for only select connections

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding

I am interested in using VPN to make my internet usage more secure, as well as untraceable. I don't like that my ISP can just watch what I do. However I would also like to run certain services on my computer (web server, minecraft server) without them being tunneled through the VPN. I got a static IP from my ISP, so I can point a domain at my computer for just such a thing. However with VPN my IP will be dynamic, and I would need to forward all incoming connections through the VPN.

I am running Windows 7 x64.

So, is there a way to setup VPN so that Chrome, Firefox, uTorrent, FileZilla, and the like can be tunneled through. But I can still connect to my computer from my normal IP, bypassing the VPN. Or perhaps it is possible for me to get a static IP/port forward in my VPN? So the domain can still point to it, and people can still access? That seems laggy, but I don't know. The normal way to do VPN in windows will not (it seems) allow for this.

My main goal here is not security, I don't plan on transmitting vital information that I need to protect, I want privacy. I do not want websites to track me by IP, or my ISP to record what sites I visit. Now if there is a way to get what I want, aside for VPN, I would be interested in hearing.

Comment: Who is maintaining the VPN server you are going to connect to? The same ISP?

Comment: It would be some company that provides VPN in the US, that will not save any information. Which service to choose I do not know, I wanted the answer to this before paying for anything.

Comment: Specify in the question (possibly make it bold) that you're using Windows. This is the kind of problem which is _very_ OS-specific

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. You set up `ipchains` rules that disallow any locally initiated traffic but response packets for incoming connections for services you are going to publish with your ISP primary connection as well as VPN traffic and DNS traffic probably. 
Then you setup routing rules that forward all other traffic over VPN connection. The more precise answer - what rules, e.t.c - could be provided after you have specific information on kind of VPN to be in used and other details clarification.

Comment: I am looking at: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/ as they keep no records. I Googled 'ipchains' and it seems to be for linux, I am running windows. Is this a problem?